# Is C an invertible matrix where CDCDC+C=0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Its a hw question so i'd prefer a hint over a solution.
We know that $C$ and $D$ are 7x7 real matrices, and need to find out whether $C$ is invertible or not, based of of the equation: $CDCDC+C=0%$.
I've got to a point where $DC=-CD$

Comment: What kind of matrix is $D$? If $D=O_{7\times 7}$ then certainly $C$ is not invertible.

Comment: It is not stated, I suppose it can be anything in which case your solution is applicable. Thanks!

Comment: Title question: no, just take $C=0$.

Comment: Yes. thanks! It was a stupid question in retrospect

Answer (score 2):

If $C$ is invertible then $C(DCDC+I)=O$ gives $(DC)^2=-I$ and $(\det{DC})^2=-1$.

Comment: Thanks! why is the n significant to your solution?

Comment: You mean $n=7$? It's significant that it is odd (since $\det(-I_n)=(-1)^n$).